# State of ifEmpty:ifNotEmpty:, ifNil:ifNotNil: and related messages across Smalltalks?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

What is the current state of messages like ifEmpty:ifNotEmpty:, ifEmpty:, ifNotEmpty: ifNil:ifNotNil:, ifNil: and ifNotNil:?

Are they available across Smalltalks, and do they behave consistently? You still see things like "object isEmpty ifTrue: [...] ifFalse: [...]" in older code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, I think the state of the art is covered very well by the [Seaside coding convetions](https://code.google.com/p/seaside/wiki/CodingConventions):

> ## Portability
>
> […]
>
> **Do not use any of these methods**, they are missing, broken or have different semantics on some platforms:
>
> […]
>
> - Object: **`#ifNotNil:`, `#ifNotNilDo:`**, `#in:`, ...
> - Boolean: `#and:and:and:`, `#or:or:or:`, ...
> - Collection: `#=`, `#pairsDo:`, `#with:collect:`
> - String: `#match:`
> - Stream: `#position`, `#position:`, **`#isEmpty`**
>
> […]

(highlighting by yours truly)

Since Seaside has been ported to Pharo, Squeak, GemStone, Dolphin, VisualWorks, VA Smalltalk, GNU Smalltalk, I think this list has some authority.

Also note that even `#isEmpty` seems to be not portable, for Streams at least.

Comment: Hmm, yes we can trust Seaside developpers, but this was true in Squeak 3.X when ifNotNil: would take no argument and ifNotNilDo: would take one... Now I would expect pretty uniform behavior of ifNil:ifNotNil: at least across latest versions of Squeak/Pharo/VW/stx/gst but I'm too lazy to check all the dialects...

Comment: Yes, I think Squeak 4.2+, Pharo 1.4+ and Gemstone 2.4+ are quite safe for the __specific__ messages. Dunno about the other dialects, either